# Is it possible to change the image without constructor? react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i want my picture to change to another picture after clicking onpress without constructor in my function.

My image code:

```html
<Image
        source={require("./assets/images/imgas.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={styles.ss}
      ></Image>
```

How do I make another image turn on when I click on it?
Because I am using a function, I cannot use constructor.

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, then call `setUri` to change the image

```js
const image = require("./assets/images/imgas.png")

const [uri, setUri] = useState(image);

<Image source={{uri}} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.ss} />
```

Comment: All is well, but I need the image to change after a click.

Comment: Using onpress, but I don't know how to do without constructor.

Comment: you should provide your complete code, that's the only way I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class Image extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
     uri: '',
     }
  }

  handleButtonPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      uri: './assets/images/imgas.png',
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <Button
        onPress={this.handleButtonPress}
        ...
      />
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need this code, but is it possible to do it without using a constructor? Becouse my entire code is embedded in:
export default function App() {